# Im cant get a doc from my documents to display

Tags: vb.net

Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub MenuItem1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MenuItem1.Click
    Me.txtFileContent.Text = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub MenuItem2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MenuItem2.Click
    Me.txtFileContent.Text = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub MenuItem3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MenuItem3.Click
    Me.savSaveFile.ShowDialog()
    Dim strFileName As String = Me.savSaveFile.FileName

    Dim fs As New FileStream(strFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
    Dim TextFile As New StreamWriter(fs)

    TextFile.Write(Me.txtFileContent.Text)

    TextFile.Close()
    fs.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub OpenToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MenuItem5.Click
    Me.savSaveFile.ShowDialog()
    Dim strFileName As String = Me.savSaveFile.FileName

    Dim fs As New FileStream(strFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    Dim TextFile As New StreamWriter(fs)

    TextFile.Close()
    fs.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class
[image: my code]
What im trying to do is display a "open" document dialog box so the text inside the box can be displayed into the text box. I did the same with the "save" document dialog box and it worked fine just confused on the Open part. Thanks a million everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different kind of dialog box for selecting files. 
One for save operations and one for opening files.

Your code seems to use the same one and from the name I think it is a `SaveFileDialog`.

To open a file you need a [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.openfiledialog%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and use a StreamReader not a StreamWriter

```
Private Sub OpenToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MenuItem5.Click
    ' Create an OpenFileDialog here, for more precise property settings see the link above'
    Dim openDlg = New OpenFileDialog()
    ' If user presses OK'
    if openDlg.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        ' Still the filename selected could be empty, need to check'
        Dim strFileName As String = openDlg.FileName
        if strFileName.Trim().Length > 0 then
           ' Open the file using a reader, not a writer'
           Using fs = New FileStream(strFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
               Using TextFile = New StreamReader(fs)
                  ' Read everything (caution this should be used only for small files)'
                  Dim fileContent = TextFile.ReadToEnd
                  ' Pass everything into a TextBox control for display'
                  Me.txtFileContent.Text = fileContent
               End Using
           End Using
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Its says ReadToEnd is not a member or systems.IO.StreamWriter

Comment: yay your awesome!! Thanks a million!!